# when the while loop ends it stops the whole script it wont loop on with the initial for(....) loop

Tags: php, while-loop

1. Problem where is the first initial loop (for($i=0;$i< $m;$i++) stops
   when the while loop ends the while loop should run for each of the
   values in the arrays p & q which should happend in the initial for
   loop. What am i doing wrong? why does the entire script stop afther
   the while() loop ends

   ```
   $p = array(1,4,16);
   $q = array(26,10,20);
   solution2($p,$q);

   // searches the prime numbers for for a given range
   // range is p[0] - q[0]
   // script needs to loop the entire array p

   // problem is afther the while loop ends the complete script ends
   // It wont continue the initial for($i=0;$i<$m;$i++){ loop
   // what am i doing wrong?
   function solution2($p, $q){

       $primes = array();
       $semieprimes = array();

       // P & Q are arrays with M intergers in it representing a range to seach prime numbers in: p[0] to q[]0], p[1] tot q[1] etc
       $m = count($p);
       echo "<br>m= ".$m."<br>";
       for($i=0;$i<$m;$i++){
           echo "i:".$i."<br>";
           $inrange = true;
           $start = $p[$i];
           $end   = $q[$i];
           $number = $start;
           echo $start."-".$end."<br>";
           while($inrange){
               // Prime number can only be divided by 1 or itself
               for($i=2;$i<=$number;$i++){
                   if(   (!($number==$i)) && (fmod($number ,$i))==0  ) {
                       echo $number." is not prime number<br>";
                       break;
                   }
                   if(($number==$i)) {
                       echo $number." is a prime number<br>";
                       $primes[] = $number;
                   }
               }
               $number++;
               if($number > $end) { $inrange = false; echo "stop?"; }
           }
           $inrange=true;
       }
       var_dump($primes);
   }
   ```
2. At the end the while loop is stopped when $number > $end (end of
   range)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$i` in both for loops. When you update it in the second loop, the first loop is going to use that new value. Use a different variable, such as `$j`, for the second `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're using $i in your outer and inner for loops. If your inner loop causes $i to be greater than or equal $m, the outer for loop will exit because of the $i